# Arabic full text search parameterised query returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

The following query

```
declare @Query NVARCHAR(100) = '"م*"'

select *
from dbo.Word
where contains([Text], @Query)
```

returns no results! However, without the parameter, it does return the expected results.

```
select *
from dbo.Word
where contains([Text], '"م*"')
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you prefix the string with N, like `N'"م*"'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **Unicode** (`nvarchar`) strings, you **must** prefix your string literals with an `N` !

Use this:

```
declare @Query NVARCHAR(100) = N'"م*"'   --see the "N" before the string?

select *
from dbo.Word
where contains([Text], @Query)
```